# Add image files while building kivy executable using pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, executable, pyinstaller, kivy-language

I wanted to create an ubuntu executable of my kivy project using pyinstaller. I have used kivy language in the project. With kivy language, I have added some images in the project. Now I wanted to make an executable. It makes executable and the executable also works fine with remaining project, except that images are not visible. 
I wanted to add the images which are in the resources folder. I don't really know how could I add these files in the project. I tries --add-data method, but that also doesn't work.

Comment: Please show the code you have to insert the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to add the image with either the `--add-data` or with the `datas` element in your `.spec` file. Then you also need to make sure that your code can find the images. I use the following code when my images are in a `resources` folder:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # this is a Pyinstaller bundle
    kivy.resources.resource_add_path(sys._MEIPASS)
    kivy.resources.resource_add_path(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'resources'))
```

And then access the image files using:

```
image_file_name = kivy.resources.resource_find('someImage.png')
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where is pyinstaller bundle code should be in. i.e. tell me the file name, to add the code.

Comment: The first piece of code (the check for a Pyinstaller bundle) should go in the main python script of your project (the one that defines your App class).  You will need an `import sys` before that code, but otherwise it could be near the top of that file, outside of any class.

Comment: Ok. got it. Thanks for the answer.